# How to refresh table in view from javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a non-partial view that is constructed from a model with results from a database.  Now when a user clicks on a button on the page, it runs an ajax call and makes a change to the underlying data.  Now I want to refresh that table of data and display a message on the screen.  At first I was refreshing the whole page, but then I couldn't figure out how to show the message.  So I'm wondering if I can simply reload the contents from the table via ajax?
I believe what I have described is enough information, but if any code is needed please let me know.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult ViewShipments()
    {
        FedExIntegration.FedExIntegration myProxy = new FedExIntegration.FedExIntegration();
        FedExIntegration.cWUPS[] shipments = myProxy.getShipmentsByRep(User.Identity.Name, "xxxxx");

        return View(shipments);
    }
```

Table:

```
<table id="shipments" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.wups)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.woeOsiRef)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.trackId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USD)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.shipWgt)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.shipDT)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.voided)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.osiDisp)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.companyName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.negRate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.shipTo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.address)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.address1)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.city)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.state)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.zip)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShipVia)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.wups)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.woeOsiRef)
                </td>
                <td class="trackID">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.trackId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    $@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USD)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shipWgt)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shipDT)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.voided)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.osiDisp)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.companyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.negRate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shipTo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.city)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.state)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.zip)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShipVia)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to refresh the table with ajax. Can you please post you table code and your controller's code?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the table in a partial view, then you can return the partial view as a string from the controller. Then all the javascript has to do is delete the old table from the page, and insert the new one in it's place. To render the partial view to a string, I would use something like this:

```
public string RenderPartialViewResultToString(PartialViewResult partialViewResult)
{
    // precondition: partialViewResult MUST either have View or ViewName specified.
    // easiest way to do this is EXPLICITLY enter the path to the view when generating the partial view
    // MVC's default mapping by method-name is NOT sufficient
    if (partialViewResult.View == null)
        partialViewResult.View = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, partialViewResult.ViewName).View;
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, partialViewResult.View, partialViewResult.ViewData, partialViewResult.TempData, stringWriter);
    partialViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
    return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax call you are using to apply underlying changes, you can use that success method of that ajax and change what ever you want to update on the page without refreshing the Page

and in place of returing View you have to return `Content("Your html code")` as string

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
url: "/route/action", 
success: function(result){
//remove olde
 $("#table").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Comment: But that call does not return the table, it just returns a message whether it succeeded or not.

Comment: if you are returing a view it will return whole view as string

Comment: just add alert and check the result what is comming

Comment: I'd recommend console.log() instead of alert, it's more readable. Particularly when checking objects or arrays.

Comment: my dear is matter of choice and in this context i am talking about text result else.